# Which Boot Camp driver version am I running?

Tags: windows-7, mac, drivers, boot-camp

I installed Boot Camp on my Mac, then Windows 7 and the specific Windows drivers from the Mac OS X installation DVD.

On the Windows side, how can I know which version of the Boot Camp driver I am running?

Comment: Bootcamp driver for what? You need drivers in Windows 7, yes, but for hardware. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the BootCamp icon in the TaskBar, then choose "About BootCamp".
On the box that appears, you can find your version number.

Answer (score 0):

BTW: what type of Mac do you have and how old is it?

Some models are not supported:

```
 **Note: The following models will not be supported for use with Windows 7 using Boot Camp.**

    iMac (17-inch, Early 2006) 
    iMac (17-inch, Late 2006) 
    iMac (20-inch, Early 2006) 
    iMac (20-inch, Late 2006) 
    MacBook Pro (15-inch, Early 2006)
    MacBook Pro (17-inch, Late 2006) 
    MacBook Pro (15-inch, Late 2006) 
    MacBook Pro (17-inch, Early 2006) 
    Mac Pro (Mid 2006, Intel Xeon Dual-core 2.66GHz or 3GHz)
```

Are you sure you're using the latest drivers? I would recommend running the Apple Software Update to make sure you do.

Comment: If you disagree with me, would you mind notifying why?

Comment: I installed the driver on the DVD but I want to know if it is the last one? DirectX is not working so I'm thinking about installing the nvidia driver.
For info : I didn't vote you down but there is each software including driver can have different version.